# Is that our new Logo?

Tags: discussion, design

In [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/meet-bubbles/), we see the following:

[image]

So, is the logo on the Tee the official, upcoming scifi.stackexchange logo? And is the new design coming soon?

Comment: Nice, that's very Batman of you to notice this.

Comment: I was hoping for a more... non-necromancer logo lol.

Comment: haha.. I'm not against it, but it seems a bit too intricate for a tiny logo. :P

Comment: I would love like a cool starfleet/space cadet/industrial logo. Something that would look good as a patch on my awesome 80's acid-washed jean jacket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry for not answering this sooner!

That is an early draft of the logo. Since I wanted Sci-Fi.SE to have a big presence at New York Comic Con, Jin expedited his design for Sci-Fi and *delivered*. I believe that a site design is on its way, and I also believe that that symbol (or one similar to it) will be the logo. The shirts were designed with limited edition-ness in mind (which is why they say NYCC for New York Comic Con on them), so if the design changes, that makes the shirts and stickers even more collectible.

Regarding the ACTUAL site design, Jin has brought his ideas [to the Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/982/design-ideas-for-gaming-site-updated-with-screenshots-v2) in the past. I'm sure once the site gets closer to an actual graduation date, he'll do the same here.

Answer (score 4):

We should totally have a logo design contest or a logo design/layout contest and have everyone choose a winnar.

UX.se already has a logo and design, and although there are hired staff as designers, part of the [7 Essentials of every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) is that a design *doesn't have to* come from the professional designers and we as a community can chose one if we so wish.

We could even have a general design contest and the hired staff could be there to make the idea a reality... or something.

Comment: I wish I could +50 this answer - this is an awesome idea! Contest! Contest! Contest!

Comment: Contests to choose designs are terrible ideas. The only thing that happens is that the most boring, inoffensive logo/design, acceptable to everyone, will be selected. We can make suggestions, but let's let Jin do his job and choose the final logo and design.

Comment: I just want something we can all look at to be proposed, lol...