# What is the modal popup background design?

Tags: support, design

The design that pops up when you add a hyperlink, image, etc... is it just a random design?  Or is it from sci-fi storyline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a custom design by [Jin](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/44/jin), Stack Exchange's resident designer. You can see a smaller version of it on the top right of the site's background, and the site's favicon is a stylized version of it. (There's also a T-shirt, but it's a limited edition only.) See also

- [Is that our new Logo?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/873/is-that-our-new-logo)
- [Design for Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/976/design-for-science-fiction-fantasy)
- [New Design Launched](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/989/new-design-launched)

Comment: Cool!  I'm a fan of Jin's work.